# Removing unknown characters from a text file

Tags: python, windows, character-encoding

I have a large number of files containing data I am trying to process using a Python script.

The files are in an unknown encoding, and if I open them in Notepad++ they contain numerical data separated by a load of 'null' characters (represented as NULL in white on black background in Notepad++).

In order to handle this, I separate the file by the null character \x00 and retrieve only numerical values using the following script:

```
stripped_data=[]
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(PATH):
    for rawfile in files:
        (dirName, fileName)= os.path.split(rawfile)
        (fileBaseName, fileExtension)=os.path.splitext(fileName)
        h=open(os.path.join(root, rawfile),'r')
        line=h.read()
        for raw_value in line.split('\x00'):
            try:
                test=float(raw_value)
                stripped_data.append(raw_value.strip())
            except ValueError:  
                pass
```

However, there are sometimes other unrecognised characters in the file (as far as I have found, always at the very beginning) - these show up in Notepad++ as 'EOT', 'SUB' and 'ETX'. They seem to interfere with the processing of the file in Python - the file appears to end at those characters, even though there is clearly more data visible in Notepad++.

How can I remove all non-ASCII characters from these files prior to processing?

Comment: If the files are correct in that unknown encoding you may want to use some logic to try if some encoding seems appropriate and read the files in that encoding. There should be some libraries / example code out there. (Just like Notepad++ opens files in a specific encoding what it sees fit.) If that’s not an option … see answer below.

Comment: I can't find any encoding which fits - think it's some weird propietary format.

Comment: You would help yourself a lot if you asked a question targeted at determining the layout and encoding of your files ... included details like (1) the source of the files (what website, what software creates them) (2) show the contents of the first few bytes of a file ... use `print repr(open('afile.ext', 'rb').read(200))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are opening the file in text mode. That means that the first Ctrl-Z character is considered as an end-of-file character. Specify 'rb' instead of 'r' in open().

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work for sure, but you could try using the IO methods in the `codec` module:

```
import codec

inFile = codec.open(<SAME ARGS AS 'OPEN'>, 'utf-8')
for line in inFile.readline():
    do_stuff()
```

You can treat the `inFile` just like a normal FILE object.

This may or may not help you, but it probably will.

**[EDIT]**

Basically you'll replace: `h=open(os.path.join(root, rawfile),'r')` with `h=open(os.path.join(root, rawfile),'r', 'utf-8')`

Comment: I assume that should read h=codecs.open(os.path.join(root, rawfile),'r', 'utf-8') - if so, it returns 'codec can't decode bytes in position 8-10: invalid data'

Answer (score 1):

The [file.read()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) function will read until EOF.
As you said it stops too early you want to continue reading the file even when hitting an EOF.
Make sure to stop when you have read the entire file. You can do this by checking the position in the file via [file.tell()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.tell) when hitting an EOF and stopping when you hit the file-size (read file-size prior to reading).

As this is rather complex you may want to use [file.next](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) and iterate over bytes.

To remove non-ascii characters you can either use a white-list for specific characters or check the read Byte against a range your define.
E.g. is the Byte between x30 and x39 (a number) -> keep it / save it somewhere / add it to a string.
See an [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: Reading the doc .next() indeed only returns lines as well. So this doesn’t help that much. You’ll have to go back to my first paragraph. Read as far as you can, when an EOF occurs, check if you’re at the end of the file (via .tell() and file-size compare) and read on if not (you may have to seek on a byte if it does not automatically when hitting an EOF). On seek() see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek